# What is the way to use dynamic imports?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic-import

#### I'm trying to use Dynamic Imports - import()

I've read this [dynamic-import documentations](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/dynamic-import)
and watched this [chrome devtools video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F3_-jTLaFSs),

and still couldn't find the right way of doing it correctly.

#### Error:

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: module is not defined

#### Boilerplate:

I've created a new project.

***no webpack, no task runners.***

just running a server with [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) node package with those files:

1. **index.html**
2. **index.js**
3. **a.js**

***index.html***:

```
<button id="btn"> Lazy load a module</button>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

***index.js***:

```
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', event => {
  import('./a.js').then(module => { console.log(module) })
});
```

***a.js***

```
module.exports = { type: 'LazyModule'}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the dynamic import function is from the ECMAScript standard while `module.exports` is a part of commonjs loaders (like browserify)

To get this to work you want to use ES Module syntax everywhere:

***index.html***: Add `type="module"` to entry file

```
<button id="btn"> Lazy load a module</button>
<script src="index.js" type="module"></script>
```

***index.js***: This one is fine

***a.js***

```
export const type = 'LazyModule';
```

---

It's important to note the method of module resolution in the browser is the same as for any other asset (links to html files, images, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, it worked :)

my lazy module is ***a.js***, so why Do I need to add type=module to ***index.js***?

Comment: The browser need to know to treat the first file as an ES Module, then it can import symbols from other ES Modules